# SSL not working between Linux and Windows

Tags: ssl

I have gone through loads of material present on internet for SSL. I followed the steps and created self signed certificate on server (linux) using keytool. Server keystore was already having an entry as ( CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown), my new certificate was second entry as ( CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server ). Then I exported the certificate(.cer) using keytool and copied same on my client(windows). I then imported server generated certificate to client trustore. Now when I try to communicate using SSL it fails everytime. I turned on SSL debug on client. Below is the log

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
  Issuer:  CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3bd2165e
  Valid from Fri Oct 21 13:08:11 IST 2016 until Thu Jan 19 13:08:11 IST 2017

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Issuer:  CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x46dac56d
  Valid from Fri Oct 21 13:20:47 IST 2016 until Thu Jan 19 13:20:47 IST 2017

***
found key for : Client
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 19643942881710234591525118408612815215632338692166465250629734200981703093763200559775845583913404371567241804832487728799610532434766533695993759141114319525441958126364976642955560446067359829730544145500409447935888670367709958247941184557182316292540918805424085096889405623367353240389104083404287642633808982388623942568195322780929142023222276129235672938020453213230922184807911898395818264624343113898437136096266829934433793735074739359988881755805184514603338282021635155460130597302085016075305135792447640646817495498043975883348791446660517781531653507565586938242488813328480016900010365926159926261191
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Oct 21 13:20:47 IST 2016,
               To: Thu Jan 19 13:20:47 IST 2017]
  Issuer: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  SerialNumber: [    46dac56d]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 72 B5 E3 14 98 BD 53 F3   69 33 96 A5 71 F5 99 2B  r.....S.i3..q..+
0010: 22 0F B9 F6                                        "...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 21 16 B3 C9 5D BC EB 71   35 78 95 8E BF 30 72 AC  !...]..q5x...0r.
0010: D1 42 AA B7 C1 8B 23 FD   67 DF 6F 36 85 E8 C6 05  .B....#.g.o6....
0020: A4 7B E7 A5 B5 3A FC 0C   88 29 3D C3 CD C2 88 8D  .....:...)=.....
0030: 86 3A BF 14 85 93 01 75   5E 6E 01 87 44 A9 0A 21  .:.....u^n..D..!
0040: A2 F0 C3 05 9C 40 7B 89   61 DB 84 28 73 89 0F 3A  .....@..a..(s..:
0050: B7 96 E8 63 30 29 8A B5   11 4C D2 7E A8 17 6F 0F  ...c0)...L....o.
0060: 4E C7 4A AD E0 A8 6E 68   CE 72 FE DD DE F7 1C 84  N.J...nh.r......
0070: 20 C9 C4 CA F1 6A 3B C0   F9 A8 DD 03 0B EF 04 03   ....j;.........
0080: 40 BA 37 F6 B6 9C BE FF   A9 E6 0E BF E6 32 B8 B3  @.7..........2..
0090: 0A EB 0F F7 EA 23 93 D1   17 D7 6E 94 0C 98 4C 90  .....#....n...L.
00A0: 40 21 DE 39 09 A9 16 2A   97 DD 2D E5 C0 FC FE 2E  @!.9...*..-.....
00B0: AE 36 0C 04 6D A8 8F 1D   B8 2B 99 54 7C AD 4F 8C  .6..m....+.T..O.
00C0: 01 9C C2 07 77 81 A7 6C   07 2D A3 75 1D 4E E4 16  ....w..l.-.u.N..
00D0: 7E D0 BD E4 79 0F B6 9C   C8 62 2E D6 E1 AC 35 58  ....y....b....5X
00E0: 22 B2 8C 4B FE 9A 06 C4   53 C1 8F 45 EA 61 3A 7F  "..K....S..E.a:.
00F0: 3C D1 15 0D A8 27 3E 0F   AB F5 8F DA 78 05 5F AE  <....'>.....x._.

]
***
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
keyStore is : D:\\Development\\Workspace\\Eclipse\\testSSL\\Sample\\.keystore
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : Client
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 19643942881710234591525118408612815215632338692166465250629734200981703093763200559775845583913404371567241804832487728799610532434766533695993759141114319525441958126364976642955560446067359829730544145500409447935888670367709958247941184557182316292540918805424085096889405623367353240389104083404287642633808982388623942568195322780929142023222276129235672938020453213230922184807911898395818264624343113898437136096266829934433793735074739359988881755805184514603338282021635155460130597302085016075305135792447640646817495498043975883348791446660517781531653507565586938242488813328480016900010365926159926261191
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Oct 21 13:20:47 IST 2016,
               To: Thu Jan 19 13:20:47 IST 2017]
  Issuer: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  SerialNumber: [    46dac56d]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 72 B5 E3 14 98 BD 53 F3   69 33 96 A5 71 F5 99 2B  r.....S.i3..q..+
0010: 22 0F B9 F6                                        "...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 21 16 B3 C9 5D BC EB 71   35 78 95 8E BF 30 72 AC  !...]..q5x...0r.
0010: D1 42 AA B7 C1 8B 23 FD   67 DF 6F 36 85 E8 C6 05  .B....#.g.o6....
0020: A4 7B E7 A5 B5 3A FC 0C   88 29 3D C3 CD C2 88 8D  .....:...)=.....
0030: 86 3A BF 14 85 93 01 75   5E 6E 01 87 44 A9 0A 21  .:.....u^n..D..!
0040: A2 F0 C3 05 9C 40 7B 89   61 DB 84 28 73 89 0F 3A  .....@..a..(s..:
0050: B7 96 E8 63 30 29 8A B5   11 4C D2 7E A8 17 6F 0F  ...c0)...L....o.
0060: 4E C7 4A AD E0 A8 6E 68   CE 72 FE DD DE F7 1C 84  N.J...nh.r......
0070: 20 C9 C4 CA F1 6A 3B C0   F9 A8 DD 03 0B EF 04 03   ....j;.........
0080: 40 BA 37 F6 B6 9C BE FF   A9 E6 0E BF E6 32 B8 B3  @.7..........2..
0090: 0A EB 0F F7 EA 23 93 D1   17 D7 6E 94 0C 98 4C 90  .....#....n...L.
00A0: 40 21 DE 39 09 A9 16 2A   97 DD 2D E5 C0 FC FE 2E  @!.9...*..-.....
00B0: AE 36 0C 04 6D A8 8F 1D   B8 2B 99 54 7C AD 4F 8C  .6..m....+.T..O.
00C0: 01 9C C2 07 77 81 A7 6C   07 2D A3 75 1D 4E E4 16  ....w..l.-.u.N..
00D0: 7E D0 BD E4 79 0F B6 9C   C8 62 2E D6 E1 AC 35 58  ....y....b....5X
00E0: 22 B2 8C 4B FE 9A 06 C4   53 C1 8F 45 EA 61 3A 7F  "..K....S..E.a:.
00F0: 3C D1 15 0D A8 27 3E 0F   AB F5 8F DA 78 05 5F AE  <....'>.....x._.

]
***
trustStore is: D:\Development\Workspace\Eclipse\testSSL\Sample\.keystore
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
  Issuer:  CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3bd2165e
  Valid from Fri Oct 21 13:08:11 IST 2016 until Thu Jan 19 13:08:11 IST 2017

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Issuer:  CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x46dac56d
  Valid from Fri Oct 21 13:20:47 IST 2016 until Thu Jan 19 13:20:47 IST 2017

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1476980696 bytes = { 63, 74, 124, 176, 200, 133, 175, 107, 173, 166, 115, 188, 94, 103, 2, 237, 54, 77, 30, 244, 166, 94, 22, 118, 220, 68, 182, 101 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 893
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1476980313 bytes = { 231, 179, 63, 173, 107, 35, 84, 125, 43, 218, 134, 171, 63, 175, 41, 97, 49, 69, 68, 114, 75, 255, 22, 5, 125, 125, 124, 228 }
Session ID:  {88, 9, 238, 89, 11, 220, 101, 208, 32, 106, 9, 30, 220, 143, 218, 47, 199, 2, 7, 90, 179, 24, 198, 139, 59, 34, 141, 169, 98, 186, 165, 87}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 95112623927847376021742911976482809760928286563374389538614118188348331948203986176617263611529390313893505980510111828145989572854367203125102386298954935692697121151897799979668903275037476471253143679337867450398842776382716002256891170241471053163351903550915614869043680655531661128282766400131123099323
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Jan 02 01:20:42 IST 2013,
               To: Sat Jan 06 01:20:42 IST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
  SerialNumber: [    50e33e12]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 3F 48 66 AE 51 1D 5C 0C   E9 0D 88 DD CD 48 84 B7  ?Hf.Q.\......H..
0010: 9A B3 70 79 C9 43 0E 4D   B1 1E 10 5B 7A EB DC 6B  ..py.C.M...[z..k
0020: 9B 15 E4 9E 9C 94 39 1C   E7 CF 0E 2C D0 A8 A0 1D  ......9....,....
0030: A1 A4 E4 63 A0 37 AA 98   72 31 77 56 16 31 49 B9  ...c.7..r1wV.1I.
0040: 8D BD A1 D7 53 BF 82 69   9C C7 B6 2A F0 FA A2 2D  ....S..i...*...-
0050: C2 34 25 23 9C DA B6 74   D5 E0 CC 27 45 A9 8C 41  .4%#...t...'E..A
0060: 23 8B 33 A8 92 72 46 77   E0 10 E7 C6 38 9D 1D A8  #.3..rFw....8...
0070: E5 B2 B3 B5 58 99 B3 BD   1C E3 B0 39 54 F2 EB 46  ....X......9T..F

]
***
CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
X.509
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
  Issuer:  CN=Server, OU=Server, O=Server, L=Server, ST=Server, C=Server
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3bd2165e
  Valid from Fri Oct 21 13:08:11 IST 2016 until Thu Jan 19 13:08:11 IST 2017

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Issuer:  CN=Client, OU=Client, O=Client, L=Client, ST=Client, C=Client
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x46dac56d
  Valid from Fri Oct 21 13:20:47 IST 2016 until Thu Jan 19 13:20:47 IST 2017

%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

When I checked logs carefully I noticed Server is sending only first certificate in chain of certificates to client i.e,. ( CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown ), my newly created certificate is not present. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you remove the Unknown certificate from the server KeyStore?

Comment: When I remove Unknown certificate, I do get my Server certificate from server and communication do happen. But that breaks other functionality on server. I can't access login page of the application. So, I guess Unknown certificate has some importance here.